# OAuth2 authentication/authorisation for API

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect

I am creating my own API server which I want to authenticate using OAuth2 (using my Azure Active Directory as an IDP).

Any client (firstparty or thirdparty) can connect to my API providing a JWT. The client will use an Azure AD (which I own) to authenticate, and will pass the Access Token obtained from the Azure AD in each request to my API server. The API server should validate the signature of the Access Token attached in the request.

I am confused how to validate the signature of the JWT. If it is RS256, should I fetch the the public key and validate on every request? (may be with caching to avoid requesting every time) But I feel I am complicating it.

*[Got more understanding after reading the comment by @Ján Halaša and updated the question accordingly]*

Comment: Do you want to multiple auth providers or just your own? By the secret, do you mean a shared key HS256 or a public key for RS256 signature?

Comment: @JánHalaša - updated the question - i want to use my own provider and want to verify using RS256 public key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an RFC for [OpenID Connect discovery](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html) endpoint which provides metadata about the OAuth2 and OpenId Connect services. Azure Active Directory [supports this endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oidc#fetch-the-openid-connect-metadata-document), but it's tenant-specific:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

The returned JSON document contains the `jwks_uri` attribute which holds a URL that can be used to get the AD's public keys in [JWK format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517). According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oidc#fetch-the-openid-connect-metadata-document), the URL should be

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys
```

You should be able to find a key with the same `kid` (key identifier) value as the `kid` value from the JWT your want validate. The key should have the following additional attributes `kty: "RSA"` (key type) and `use: "sig"` (used for JWT signing).

When you get the key, you just decrypt the signature part of the JWT being verified and compare it to the hash you make from the other two parts of the JWT (the hashes must be the same).

You can cache the JWK keys, since its values should not change - if there is a new key, it will get a new unique `kid`. Probably the only problematic situation is if a key gets removed from the JWKS document, so it's up to you how long you will cache it.

Comment: Thanks @Ján Halaša - it really helps and answers my question. A quick question though - as I am not finding many examples or a good pattern to use the public key to verify the  token signature, just wondering if I am missing something - Is this the only way to go when I am developing the resource server and when I am depending on a third party IDP?

Comment: JWT is usually used for ID tokens from OpenId Connect. So you will find this RSA key distribution described in documents about OpenId Connect. OAuth2 access tokens are often in form of a random string and need to be verified at the `/token` endpoint, which allows the authentication provider (Azure AD) to revoke tokens. But reading the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens#validating-tokens), you are probably using ID tokens.